# How to send chat only in my contact Whatsapp-web-js

Tags: javascript, bots, whatsapp

so currently i'm using [Whatsapp-web.js](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js), and i want to send message only someone in my contact when they are send message to me. how to do that?

I already try this:

```js
const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const client = new Client();

client.on('qr', (qr) => {
    // Generate and scan this code with your phone
    console.log('QR RECEIVED', qr);
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.body == '!ping') {
        msg.reply('pong');
    }
});

client.initialize();
```

**but someone in group can acces that, what i want is only someone in my contact**

Answer (score 1):

Are you need whatsapp bot reply on only messages come from one contact and ignore others contacts?
Use this codes to check messages come from any number.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.from == '999999999@c.us'){
        if (msg.body == '!ping') {
            msg.reply('pong');
        }
    }
});
```

Don't forget change '999999999' to your number with country code without '+'.